# Why does this print 5?

Tags: arrays, c++11

Suppose we have the following:

```
int array[][2]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};

cout << ( * ( array + 1 ) )[2] << endl;
```

I do not understand why this prints 5.

I think that (array + 1) gives us an int *[2] to {3, 4}, so, what we can think of as the second row. Let's call this pointer ptr.

(* ptr)[2]

Is this saying that I should dereference ptr and then print whatever is at index 2? Doesn't dereferencing ptr give me an int * that points to number 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(array + 1)` points to 3, which is the same as `(array + 1)[0]`

then:

```
(array + 1)[0] = 3
(array + 1)[1] = 4
(array + 1)[2] = 5
```

Arrays start at 0

Comment: Could you clarify how I should think about the asterisk? With the outer parentheses, I thought I had to think about dereferencing before doing anything with the subscript.

Comment: *(array +1) is the same as array[1], so (*(array +1))[2] is the same as (array[1])[2]

Answer (score 0):

Because you have an array of [][2], so 2 elements and you are accessing by index 2 which is actually 3rd number (0, 1, 2)